# Carregar arquivo (imagem), com PHP para enviar para AWS S3

Tags: php, imagem, arquivo, stream-de-arquivos

Atualmente eu tenho um script que eu recebo a imagem a partir de um post como este:

```
$amazonS3 = new AmazonAwsS3;
$amazonS3->uploadFile($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['anexo']['name'], "sig/$class/$idAmdamento");
```

porém ao inves de eu pegar esse arquivo de um POST, eu preciso agora pegar o arquivo dentro de um diretório e carrega-lo para a amazonS3, mas eu não estou conseguindo faze-lo. tentei ler com o file(), readfile(), file_get_content() ex: `$arquivo = readfile('../arquivos/chamados/anexo_1377633937.jpg');` mas o array vem vazio....
nesse caso eu consigo fazer o download da imagem, mas não consigo ler a imagem e armazena-la no temp do PHP para envia-la para outro local

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$a->getArquivoNome().';');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header ('Content-Length: '.filesize('../arquivos/chamados/'.$a->getArquivo()));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile('../arquivos/chamados/anexo_1377633937.jpg');
```

alguém pode me ajudar? :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$amazonS3 = new AmazonAwsS3;
$directory = '/path/to/my/directory';
$scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
foreach($scanned_directory as $f){
    $amazonS3->uploadFile($directory.$f, $directory.$f, "sig/$class/$idAmdamento");
    // se for colocar o exclui file cria o unlink
    // @unlink($directory.$f);
}
```

Na verdade, você só vai pegar o NOME DO ARQUIVO DE ORIGEM e NOME DO ARQUIVO NO DESTINO não precisa passar necessariamente um ponteiro para o registro e sim os filenames

Comment: cara, muito obrigado, eu sei que a formulação da minha pergunta não foi boa, mas você tirou um tempo para responde-la e me ajudou muito mesmo, obrigado.